Have a FastAPI app that accesses data from a main program loop
I'm writing a program that will track a server's SSH connection over time. As such, I have put it in a main loop similar to the following:
class ConnectionCheckEngine():

    def __init__(self):
       self.data = list()

    def run(self):
       while True:
           self.data.append(self.get_connection_info())
           time.sleep(30)

I want to be able to access this data via an API using FastAPI. How can I allow FastAPI to access any data while the main loop is running? Is it as simple as having the main loop run like so:

cce = ConnectionCheckEngine()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cce.run()

and then having all of my routes defined above it, such as:
app = FastAPI()
cce = ConnectionCheckEngine()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {'data': cce.data}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cce.run()

This is on python 3.13.0

Does this answer your question? You might find this, as well as and this and this helpful as well

You want to use a lifespan event to start the loop when the app starts: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#lifespan

@Chris your example #3 proved to work perfectly, thanks!
